# How to avoid errors when using pROC within a loop/function?

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

How do I pass arguments to the `pROC::roc()` function when used in a loop/function? I've tried a number of different approaches: `!!sym(i)`, `{{i}}`, `as.name(i)`, and using non-formula syntax e.g. `roclist <- roc(response, i, df, quiet = TRUE)`. Based on [the source code](https://github.com/cran/pROC/blob/master/R/roc.R) I suspect the issue is the spaces in the variable names and the "``" syntax. I've also looked at the source code for the `roc_()` function but i couldn't get that to work either.

Example data:

```r
df <- structure(list(response = c("Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", 
                                  "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", 
                                  "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", 
                                  "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", 
                                  "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", 
                                  "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", 
                                  "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", 
                                  "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", 
                                  "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", 
                                  "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit", "No_Benefit"), `Col 1` = c(436, 
                                                                                                       304, 594, 360, 234, 1751, 52, 93, 600, 613, 442, 196, 2231, 274, 
                                                                                                       204, 703, 392, 189, 139, 282, 201, 256, 382, 777, 514, 648, 175, 
                                                                                                       484, 551, 135, 497, 731, 101, 420, 49, 378, 1015, 887, 283, 386, 
                                                                                                       2439, 1006, 294, 296, 66, 317, 73, 131, 1515, 573, 233, 122, 
                                                                                                       403, 538, 544, 61, 118, 39, 356, 87, 453, 337, 124, 112, 362, 
                                                                                                       315, 264, 450, 511, 132, 78, 36, 109, 78, 503, 280, 105, 567, 
                                                                                                       676, 132, 323, 356, 409, 277, 171, 114, 248, 36, 331, 510, 91, 
                                                                                                       116, 263, 152, 259, 137, 171, 278, 198, 247), Col_2 = c(417, 
                                                                                                                                                               267, 561, 340, 218, 1681, 50, 90, 566, 566, 424, 184, 2044, 258, 
                                                                                                                                                               195, 665, 374, 181, 126, 262, 193, 249, 351, 717, 499, 589, 168, 
                                                                                                                                                               437, 505, 125, 451, 684, 97, 392, 44, 352, 915, 825, 259, 362, 
                                                                                                                                                               2238, 940, 264, 267, 63, 293, 70, 116, 1383, 538, 209, 118, 386, 
                                                                                                                                                               510, 514, 55, 110, 38, 338, 78, 434, 326, 112, 108, 340, 281, 
                                                                                                                                                               252, 418, 485, 128, 77, 35, 100, 73, 465, 257, 102, 534, 628, 
                                                                                                                                                               127, 297, 345, 391, 257, 149, 108, 229, 33, 307, 472, 84, 105, 
                                                                                                                                                               246, 137, 241, 120, 156, 251, 179, 235), `3` = c(9.832, 15.356, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                15.865, 18.529, 15.138, 13.623, 10, 11.111, 12.014, 16.784, 15.094, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                16.304, 13.209, 8.915, 7.692, 13.534, 10.963, 6.63, 19.048, 11.069, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                11.399, 4.819, 16.524, 17.992, 7.615, 12.054, 11.905, 13.959, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                14.851, 6.4, 15.743, 23.246, 8.247, 11.48, 22.727, 16.477, 14.645, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                8.242, 15.058, 15.47, 15.103, 11.064, 15.53, 19.85, 7.937, 14.676, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                15.714, 17.241, 15.04, 16.171, 13.876, 13.559, 30.829, 11.373, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                17.899, 14.545, 14.545, 15.789, 8.876, 10.256, 6.682, 14.11, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                16.071, 22.222, 12.647, 18.505, 8.333, 15.789, 15.052, 18.75, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                5.195, 17.143, 17, 15.068, 13.548, 15.953, 16.667, 22.659, 12.261, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                16.535, 10.101, 30.725, 14.834, 8.56, 20.134, 12.963, 14.41, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                18.182, 13.355, 15.254, 20.238, 13.333, 11.789, 14.599, 14.523, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                27.5, 14.744, 19.522, 20.67, 15.319)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   response = c("Benefit", "No_Benefit"), .rows = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1:50, 51:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

My code so far (runs as expected, but not with lapply):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(pROC)
#> Type 'citation("pROC")' for a citation.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pROC'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     cov, smooth, var

list_of_variables_to_plot <- colnames(df[-c(1)])

plot_roc_curves <- function(i) {
  roclist <- roc(response ~ i, df, quiet = TRUE)
  ggroc(roclist, legacy.axes = TRUE) +
    annotate("text", label = sprintf("AUC: %.2f (%.2f-%.2f)",
                                     roclist$auc, ci(roclist)[1], 
                                     ci(roclist)[3]), 
             x = 0.1, y = 0.75, hjust = 0) +
    annotate("segment", x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1,
             color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 18) +
    ggtitle(paste("Test",
                  i, sep = ": ")) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1),
              fill = NA, color = "black", linewidth = 0.05) +
    theme(title = element_text(size = 11))
}

## Plot the data (one plot per page)
pdf(file = paste0("test_output_",
                  gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()),
                  ".pdf"), width = 7, height = 7)
lapply(list_of_variables_to_plot, plot_roc_curves)
#> Error in model.frame.default(formula = response ~ i, data = df, na.action = "na.pass"): variable lengths differ (found for 'i')
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? There's much more to your code than calling the `roc` function, so it's hard to know what the "best" way would look like.

Comment: That being said you're right, there's definitely a bug with spaces in column names. I'll look into it.

Comment: My actual use case is pretty similar to the example; I have ~40,000 variables and I typically plot them using ggplot with one variable per page of a pdf. This makes it easy to scroll through and stop scrolling when I see something interesting. I wanted to do the same thing with pROC, but I can't use the same syntax I use with ggplot (i.e. `!!sym(i)`). I posted the 'workaround' I use as an answer below, but I suspect there's a NSE way to do it and I just couldn't figure it out (nothing on SO or any other forum as far as I could see). Thanks for the reply; there's no rush as `df[[column]]` works

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to a variable by name in a formula.

This won't work with any function taking a formula as input:

```
> fit_glm <- function(i) {
  model <- glm(response ~ i, data = df)
}
lapply(list_of_variables_to_plot, fit_glm)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = response ~ i, data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'i')
```

Formulas and tidyverse-style non standard evaluation are great for the end user, but they are a nightmare to program with. I would avoid using them with a function, they are totally unnecessary in that context.

Use good old standard R evaluation, preferably passing parameters explicitly.

```
plot_roc_curves <- function(predictor, response, df) {
  roc_curve <- roc(df[[response]], df[[predictor]], quiet = TRUE)
  ...
}
lapply(list_of_variables_to_plot, plot_roc_curves, df=df, response="response")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand the formula syntax isn't appropriate the way I was using it; I tried a few different things and got errors every time. If I wanted to do a 'fit_glm' type function, I would use `df %>% map(~summary(lm(df$\`col 1\` ~ .x))$r.squared)`, rather than use lapply, but I don't know how to use that type of approach and get one ROC plot per page in a pdf. Happy to add any other details if it would help @Calimo. Thanks for taking the time to explain where I'm going wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the formula syntax in the `roc()` function you can use `data[[i]]`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(pROC)

plot_roc_curves <- function(i) {
  roclist <- roc(df$response, df[[i]], quiet = TRUE)
  ggroc(roclist, legacy.axes = TRUE) +
    annotate("text", label = sprintf("AUC: %.2f (%.2f-%.2f)",
                                     roclist$auc, ci(roclist)[1], 
                                     ci(roclist)[3]), 
             x = 0.1, y = 0.75, hjust = 0) +
    annotate("segment", x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1,
             color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 18) +
    ggtitle(paste("Test",
                  i, sep = ": ")) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1),
              fill = NA, color = "black", linewidth = 0.05) +
    theme(title = element_text(size = 11))
}

list_of_variables_to_plot <- colnames(df[-c(1)])

## Plot the data (one plot per page)
pdf(file = paste0("test_output_",
                  gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()),
                  ".pdf"), width = 7, height = 7)
lapply(list_of_variables_to_plot, plot_roc_curves)
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> [[3]]
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image: example.png]

Not sure if this is the 'best' way, but it 'works'.

Comment: Specifically the problem is that you cannot refer to a variable like `i` in a formula. This is not NSE!

Comment: Yep, it's not NSE, that's the whole point of the question - I wanted to use the same syntax I use in ggplot and I couldn't work out a solution